# Loading instance of an Activity from saved state while using IntentService

Tags: android, service, intentservice

I have an `Activity`, from there I start a task (consider like uploading multiple files to server) using `IntentService`. Once each and every upload is completed I send back the result of upload to `Activity` using `ResultReceiver`. I'm getting the result back to an `Activity` and updating the UI.

While uploading the files, I close my `Activity`. `IntentService` is still running and returning the result. But `Activity` is not alive to receive the result as it was destroyed. Now again I open the `Activity` I want to continue to show the uploading progress. But it's not happening. I'm sharing the code what I have done.

**MyResultReceiver.java**

```
public class MyResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

    private Receiver receiver;

    public MyResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    public void setReceiver(Receiver receiver) {
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }

    public interface Receiver {
        public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        if (receiver != null) {
             receiver.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        }
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    resultReceiver = new MyResultReceiver(new Handler());
    resultReceiver.setReceiver(new MyResultReceiver.Receiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                isCompleted = resultData.getBoolean("IsCompleted");
                textView.setText(resultData.getString("Message"));
            }
        }
    });

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyIntentService.class);
    intent.putExtra("receiver", resultReceiver);
    startService(intent);
}
```

**MyIntentService.java**

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(final Intent intent) {

    for (int count = 0; count <= i; count--) {
        ResultReceiver receiver = intent.getParcelableExtra("receiver");
        i -= 1;
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        if (count == i)
            bundle.putBoolean("IsCompleted", true);
        else
            bundle.putBoolean("IsCompleted", false);

        bundle.putString("Message", "This is " + i);

        receiver.send(Activity.RESULT_OK, bundle);
        Log.i("Intent Service", "This is " + i);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above code all I'm trying to display the decremented count in `TextView`.

I have tried using `onSaveInstanceState`, but according to the documentation it just saves only when OS decides. In my case I want to store this data all time and restore it whenever the activity is re-created.

Any help or reference will be encouraged.

**EDIT** : How I tried to store and restore the instance

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyIntentService.class);
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
   intent.putExtra("receiver", savedInstanceState.getParcelable("savedReceiver"));
} else
   intent.putExtra("receiver", resultReceiver);
startService(intent);
```

I tried something like this. But didn't help. And I can't use `savedInstanceState` as it will not be called all the time. Hope this help!

Comment: Have you thought of using saving data in preferences ?

Comment: Yeah, but what I want to save is parcelable data!  If you look into my code,  in `onCreate` method, I will be starting the `Service`. There I pass extras through `Intent`. I believe I should hold that data as instance in preference!